# Ajax sends data successfully to IE but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

Hello I have the following data being through ajax to an MVC Controller. It works perfectly fine when it runs on IE, but receives an error when it runs on firefox. I tried changing so many things (adding dataTypes, contentType... and so on). Most of them result in the data not being sent through IE as well.

```
function sendData() {
    var currData = new Array();
    var elements = document.getElementById("formID").elements;
    for (var i = 0, element; element = elements[i++];) {
        if (element.value != "Submit Query") {
            if (element.value != "") {
                currData.push(element.value);
            }
        }
    }
    var finData = {values: currData};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "home/sendcurr",
        data: finData,
        traditional: true,
        success: function (recData) {
            populateObjData(recData);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

In the controller I receive the data as:

```
List<String> values
```

And return the following data back to the ajax on success.

```
var jsonData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_object);
return jsonData;
```

Again this as of right now works perfectly in IE but not Firefox!
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What's `traditional: true` doing here?

Comment: what error you getting in firefox?

Comment: @PraveenKumar this was the only way that I had figured out to be able to read the data when received by the controller in IE, otherwise it just gave me "null" instead of the list of values in the array.

Comment: @Baraa That's what causing FF to fail I guess. Do one thing. Create two separate AJAX functions, one for IE and one for others. Have `traditional: true` in IE and for others, don't include that. See if that works?

Comment: @PraveenKumar will try it

Comment: @Baraa Waiting for your response as an AJAX Response. ;)

Comment: Check your console for errors, check your network tab to see what data is being sent and received.

Comment: Ok well so I reran the above code to get the error and it worked for firefox...I have no idea how that happened besides not having my javascript refreshed into the new change I made. Well...what is weird though is the following if statement makes IE not work but works in firefox: if (element.value != "Submit Query" || element.value = "") What is the difference between this if statement and the above 2 if statements?

Comment: If someone replies with what I assume is the answer which my javascript was not refreshed? I will accept as answer as it works now for both. I feel dumb btw. Sorry for your time! It is much appreciated.

Comment: @Baraa This if (element.value != "Submit Query" || element.value = "") is a mistake in IE, FF, Chrome last version: The mistake or typo is: element.value = "". The right form is  if (element.value != "Submit Query" || element.value == "") otherwise you have: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: Why serialize by yourself? Use the `$.serialize()` method from jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing your code with IE11 + Chrome50 annd FF46 I obtained the following results if I use or not [the traditional style of param serialization.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

```
traditional: true:
Chrome  -->  "["values=1","values=2","values=Submit%20Query"]"
FF      -->  "["values=1","values=2","values=Submit%20Query"]"
IE      -->  "[values=1,values=2,values=Submit%20Query]"
traditional: false:
Chrome -->  "["values%5B%5D=1","values%5B%5D=2","values%5B%5D=Submit%20Query"]"
FF     -->  "["values%5B%5D=1", "values%5B%5D=2", "values%5B%5D=Submit%20Query"]"
IE     -->  "[values%5B%5D=1,values%5B%5D=2,values%5B%5D=Submit%20Query]"
```

Using instead [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the results are:

```
Chrome: --> "["firstName=1","lastName=2"]"
FF      --> "["firstName=1", "lastName=2"]"
IE:     --> "[firstName=1,lastName=2]"
```

For the if problem I wrote a comment on the mistake.

So, I may suggest you to reduce the lines of code and write something like:

```js
function sendData() {
  var finData = $('#formID').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "z.html",
    data: finData,
    success: function (recData) {
      //populateObjData(recData);
      alert('success');
    },
    error: function () {
      alert("error");
    }
  });
}
$(function () {
  $('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    sendData();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>


<form id="formID" action="z.html" method="post">
    <input name="firstName" value="1">
    <input name="lastName" value="2">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Query">
</form>
```

If you are interested to debug the jQuery code you may take a look to:

```
jQuery.param = function( a, traditional ) {
```

Comment: thanks for the in depth analysis, this helps to understand more!